# How to access json format column in a pyspark/snowpark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a pyspark/snowpark dataframe as below. I am partitioning by table and sequence column and creating a list as below

```
df = session.create_dataframe(
    [('a', 'xx', {
  "a": {
    "flag": "Y",
    "num": -12,
    "CD": [
      "403",
      "402",
      "405",
      "404"
    ],
    "RANGE_NUM": 999,
    "COL_NM": "COL1"
  }
}),
     ('a', 'xx', {
  "b": {
    "flag": "N",
    "num": -12,
    "CD": [
      "401"
    ],
    "RANGE_NUM": 999,
    "COL_NM": "COL2"
  }
}),
     ('b', 'z', {"c": {
    "flag": "N",
    "num": -12,
    "CD": [
      "411"
    ],
    "RANGE_NUM": 999,
    "COL_NM": "COL3"
  }})],
    ['table', 'seq', 'col']
)

df.show()
-------------------------------------------
|"TABLE"  |"SEQ"  |"COL"                  |
-------------------------------------------
|a        |xx     |{                      |
|         |       |  "a": {               |
|         |       |    "CD": [            |
|         |       |      "403",           |
|         |       |      "402",           |
|         |       |      "405",           |
|         |       |      "404"            |
|         |       |    ],                 |
|         |       |    "COL_NM": "COL1",  |
|         |       |    "RANGE_NUM": 999,  |
|         |       |    "flag": "Y",       |
|         |       |    "num": -12         |
|         |       |  }                    |
|         |       |}                      |
|a        |xx     |{                      |
|         |       |  "b": {               |
|         |       |    "CD": [            |
|         |       |      "401"            |
|         |       |    ],                 |
|         |       |    "COL_NM": "COL2",  |
|         |       |    "RANGE_NUM": 999,  |
|         |       |    "flag": "N",       |
|         |       |    "num": -12         |
|         |       |  }                    |
|         |       |}                      |
|b        |z      |{                      |
|         |       |  "c": {               |
|         |       |    "CD": [            |
|         |       |      "411"            |
|         |       |    ],                 |
|         |       |    "COL_NM": "COL3",  |
|         |       |    "RANGE_NUM": 999,  |
|         |       |    "flag": "N",       |
|         |       |    "num": -12         |
|         |       |  }                    |
|         |       |}                      |
-------------------------------------------

w = W.partitionBy(['table','seq']).orderBy(['table','seq'])
lst = df.withColumn('row', F.row_number().over(w)).collect()
lst
```

I want to loop through each element of the lst and have the value of the column stored  as below.How to I access CD, num, flag from column "COL"?

```
for row in lst:
   tbl = row["TABLE"]
   seq = row["SEQ"]
   cd = ?
   num =?
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python Way**
To iterate your collected list from the example, you can do this:

```
for row in lst:
  tbl = row["table"]
  seq = row["seq"]
  cd_values = []
  for key, value in row['col'].items():
        cd_values.append(value['CD'])

  num_values = []
  for key, value in row['col'].items():
        num_values.append(value['num'])
```

**PySpark Way**
You can use `f.explode` twice to get to the desired level of `CD` and `num`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# Select 'table', 'seq', and explode 'col' into separate rows
exploded_df = df.select('table', 'seq', f.explode('col'))

# Select 'table', 'seq', 'key', and explode 'value' into separate rows
key_value_df = exploded_df.select('table', 'seq', 'key', f.explode('value').alias('key2', 'value2'))
```

To then extract only the values you want you can filter the dataframe so you only have the values `CD` in one dataframe and the values for `num` in the other.

```
# Keep only rows where the value in 'key2' is 'CD'
cd_df = key_value_df.filter(f.col('key2') == 'CD')

# Keep only rows where the value in 'key2' is 'num'
num_df = key_value_df.filter(f.col('key2') == 'num')
```

Then you only have to join the two dataframes to get your result.

```
# Join 'cd_df' and 'num_df' on 'table', 'seq', and 'key' with a left join
joined_df = cd_df.withColumnRenamed('value2', 'CD').join(num_df.withColumnRenamed('value2', 'num'), on=['table', 'seq', 'key'], how='left')
    
# Select the columns 'table', 'seq', 'key', 'CD', and 'num' and display the resulting DataFrame
joined_df.select('table', 'seq', 'key', 'CD', 'num').show()
```

The expected result of your example should then be:

```
| table | seq | key | CD                   | num |
|-------|-----|-----|----------------------|-----|
| a     | xx  | a   | [403, 402, 405, 404] | -12 |
| a     | xx  | b   | [401]                | -12 |
| b     | z   | c   | [411]                | -12 |
```

Comment: That’s not the intension. I just want to loop through each element of the lst and access the value of say CD, num, flag as I have done for column Table and seq

Comment: Okay sure, you can also just iterate the collected list. It is not really the PySpark way and won't scale. But see my updated answer.

Comment: When I do this in pyspark I am getting "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'" error. Is there a way to replicate the same in pyspark?